# Sorting a complex multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this complex array that I need to sort by value that is deep inside the array.

here's the array structure:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'data' => array(
              'tree_id'   => 0,
              'title_tag' => 'Annex A',
        ),
        'nodes' => array(
             array(
                 array(
                     'data'  => array(
                          'tree_id' => 0,
                          'title_tag' => 'Annex A'
                     ),
                     'attachments' => array(
                          'title_tag' => 'Annex A',
                          'updated_by' => 'Steve'
                     )
                 ) 
             ),
             array(
                 array(
                      'data'  => array(
                      'tree_id' => 0,
                      'title_tag' => 'Annex B'
                 ),
                 'attachments'   => array(
                     'title_tag' => 'Annex B',
                     'updated_by'  => 'Steve'
                 )
              )
          )
      )
   )
);
```

I would like to sort the $array[ array[nodes][array][array][data]['title_tag'] ] alphabetically.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
foreach( $array as $arr ){
    foreach( $arr['nodes'] as $node ){
        foreach( $node as $data ){
            $keys[] = $data['data']['title_tag'];
        }
        array_multisort($keys,SORT_DESC,$node);
    }
```

}

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I'd like to view arrays like that when debugging. Sorry if you find it excessive.

Comment: So do you want to sort the nodes array?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon basically yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a user-defined sort...

```
function my_array_sort($a, $b) {

    // compare the 2 elements
    return strnatcmp ( $a[0][data]['title_tag'], $b[0][data]['title_tag'] );

}

foreach( $array as $arr ) {

    uasort($arr['nodes'], "my_array_sort");

}
```

but seriously man I recommend making a class that is the "node" object. It will make your code much nicer to use and allow to have a definite structure, without you having to remember every key name.

You also do not need to wrap each node twice in an array object. This will do the same thing...

```
'nodes' => array(
              array(
                  'data'  => array(
                       'tree_id' => 0,
                       'title_tag' => 'Annex A'
                  ),
                  'attachments' => array(
                       'title_tag' => 'Annex A',
                       'updated_by' => 'Steve'
                  )
              ),
              array(
                  'data'  => array(
                      'tree_id' => 0,
                      'title_tag' => 'Annex B'
                 ),
                 'attachments'   => array(
                      'title_tag' => 'Annex B',
                      'updated_by'  => 'Steve'
                 )
              )
           );
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your thoughts about this man, I'll consider your suggestion next time. But I had figured it out. I'll mark this answer as check..